# Rechecking baggage for AA flight Paris-->New York-->Boston

Tags: luggage, new-york-city, american-airlines

I'll soon be flying from Paris, France (Charles de Gaulle Airport) to New York, USA with a connecting flight to Boston, USA. The flight is with American Airlines.

Will I need to claim and then recheck my baggage in New York before my flight to Boston?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, when entering the US by air, you always pass through customs at your first US stop, at which point you have to claim and recheck your luggage.

The only exceptions is if your origin or another stopover is at a  "preclearance" airport outside the US, in which case you clear US customs there.  Most of these are in Canada and CDG is not one.

Comment: Available [preclearance location](http://www.cbp.gov/xp/cgov/toolbox/contacts/preclearance/preclear_locations.xml)